# Session expiring on application pool restart

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

We have a web application built in **ASP MVC 4**.

We are storing our session data in database i.e. `sessionState mode="SQLServer"`

When we restart the application pool, we expect the session not to expire. However, for some reason it does. Session_end is not being called, however Session_Start is called.

Please can anyone suggest why this could be happening.

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked if your objects kept are serializable? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586(v=vs.140).aspx

Comment: Yes we made sure all objects were serializable before enabling SQLServer session state.

Comment: How do you serialize the objects, may I ask?

Comment: We have marked the classes with Serializable attribute

Comment: How about the installation guide using Aspnet_regsql.exe? have you followed it well? It works fine with me based from the steps mentioned in the url.